# Using preg_replace in this?

Tags: php, regex

Hi I want to replace text inside the single quotes in line

```
$key = 'ABC';
```

I wrote this PHP code, :

```
$data = '$key = \'ABC\'';
preg_match($data, '/s$key = \'(.*)\'\;/s', $security_key);
print_r($security_key);
```

but it's giving warnings like Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending matching delimiter '>'

Comment: use str_replace if your only replacing a string http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = '$key = \'ABC\'';
$replacement = 'CBA';
$data = preg_replace("/'[^']*'/", "'$replacement'", $data);
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression must begin and end with a [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) - %,/,$,#,~...

Try this:

```
$data = '%$key = \'ABC\'%';
preg_match($data, '/s$key = \'(.*)\'\;/s', $security_key);
print_r($security_key);
```